# Build job when certain files have been updated

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a Jenkinsfile to do a number of checks on a repo. The check runs everytime a PR has been created. The goal of my check is to make sure that in my PR, 2 particularly files (a.txt) and (b.txt) have been changed.

The issue is that these 2 files always must be changed when a PR is issued and I dont want my developers to forget about updating these files. So I want to write a check that fails the build if these 2 files have not been updated. I tried something like this

```
        stage('Check if file changed'){
          when {
             allOf {
              changeset "a.txt"
              changeset "b.txt"
            }
          }
            steps {
              // Do something
            }
        }
```

But the issue with this is that it wants the change to happen in the commit. A developer could create a PR with one file updated and then add another commit to update the other file but this check will always want both files updated in the latest commit. Can someone suggest a way for me to accomplish what I need ? Also in the above case, it doest fail the build if a file is not updated. It just skips the stage. I want the build to fail. Any suggestions ?

Locally running gives me the following output

```
git diff --name-status master
M   CHANGELOG.md
M   Jenkinsfile
```

I want to use this in my jenkins build but there I get the error

```
+ git diff --name-status master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
script returned exit code 128
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you have used in `allOf{}` inside `when{}` DSL is wrong. It would be something like this

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            when { 
                allOf{
                    changeset "README.md"; changeset "README-one.md"
                } 
            }
            steps {
                echo "from build"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**note** : both `changeset` has to be seperate with `;` not `,` or `space`. I can see In Jenkins documentation they have mention `,` - might be thats a mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multi branch pipeline, you could do a git diff between $GIT_COMMIT and $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT. Note that when the job is triggered for the first time for a branch, $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT is non existent, during which you can assume the files `a.txt` and `b.txt` changed.